# Can't use drag_and_drop to move slider with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to use the following code to move a slider with Selenium Webdriver, but I get an error that says: "selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: POST /session/38618f26-c271-41f3-a019-990ee2558063/moveto did not match a known command"

I use selenium 3.0.2 and Firefox 51.0.1 What am I doing wrong? How else can I move a slider?

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get("http://url_wuth_a_slider")

source_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_to_slider_knob")
destination_element = browser.find_element_by_xpath("xpath_to_destination")
ActionChains(browser).drag_and_drop(source_element, destination_element).perform()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a [known issue with the selenium bindings and geckodriver](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/issues/2285). It seems to work fine in Chrome. It may work in Firefox if you disable marrionette (but you may need to use a version of Firefox pre-50):

```
browser = webdriver.Firefox(capabilities = { "marionette": False })
```

But your best bet is Chrome.